# Play Stage command in windows

Tags: windows, playframework-2.0, openshift

I am trying to deploy my Play! application on OpenShift from windows machine.

However as Play "stage" command is meant for Linux based systems, I am not sure how to proceed with staging. I am able to connect to SSH but since play is not present there, play command doesnt work there. Is there any way to manually do what "stage" command does.

Any idea how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know OpenShift's deployment cycle, however, you can use a `play dist` command to prepare standalone version of application like the `stage` command, but  it will generate a zip file, instead writing the code into target directory.

Comment: That worked thanks! I had to extract the zip place it in target folder before pushing changes so that OpenShift action_hook start script picks it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote down on Github my [checklist](https://github.com/thomson256/play-diy-scripts) that i had for myself.
Basically the scripts on .openshift do the trick (scripts aren't written by me).

`play stage` on windows isn't even meant to be supported by the Play developers http://bit.ly/170Wx6w